# Force opening and reading zip files from php

Tags: php, archive, fopen, winrar

This may be a simple question or a pretty complex one, ill let you be the deciders.

Using PHP To open a zip file, extract the files to a directory and close the zip file is not a complicated class to make.

But lets say that the file is not a zip, but yet is able to be read by *WinRar*, examples of these files are like exe's SFX archives etc.

What factors do all these files have in conmen to allow *WinRar* to browse the source of them.

Another example is Anti Virus Software, that individually scan files within an EXE ?

So what an example:

```
$handle = fopen("an_unknown_file.abc", "rb");
while (!feof($handle))
{
    //What generic code could I use to determain weather the file can be extracted ?
}
fclose($handle);
```

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zip's specifications allow the actual "zip" file portion to be embedded ANYWHERE within a file. It doesn't necessarily have to start at position '0' in the file. This is how self-extracting zips work. It's a small .exe stub program which has a larger .zip file appended to the end of it.

Finding a zip is mostly a matter of scanning for a zip file's "magic number" within a file, then doing a few heuristics to determine if it's really a zip file, or just something random that happens to contain a zip's magic number.

A .docx file is really just a .zip that contains various XML files representing a Word file's contents. Just like a .jar is a zip file that contains various different chunks of Java code.

Winrar's got a bunch of extra code within it to scan through a file and look for any identifiable "this is a compress archive" type signatures, one of which happens to be that of a zip file's.

There's nothing too magical about it. It's just a matter of scanning through a file and looking for signatures.

Comment: Brilliant Answer, This is the information I was seeking, Do you have any links to some papers regarding the Zip's "Magic Number(s)" that I can read up on. Thanks

Comment: Not offhand, but I'm sure you can find something on google quickly. For a "basic" zip file, you could look in any unix system's "magic" file, which would have the magic number and the heuristics to locate it.

Comment: The magic number is `PK`, i have found the way to discover archives hidden in all types of files, Thanks :)

Comment: Just want out that you don't mistakenly try to extract a file that lists griefers in an MMO or something. Just because 'PK' show up doesn't mean it's a zip... still have to do the other heuristics.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly is your question, but I think you are confusing something here... File extension can be described as just a convenient way for humans and computers to relate file extensions to the type of the file/programs that work with them. WinRar (or any other program) reads what the file contains and if it can understand it - it works with it. The only important thing is that the file format (data in the file) is valid and that the program you are using can work with this file format.

So, if a file is in any format that WinRar can work with (.rar, .zip, .gz, etc.), it's extension could be .txt or .whatever and WinRar will still be able to work with it. Extension is just for convenience.

Comment: Sorry for the miss understanding, I understand extensions and content types, my question is what determins a archive file from a regular file, Take `.docx` file, which is a word file, this would not have the same structure as a `.rar` winrar archived file, but there must be similarities as winrar is able to read the content files within them.

Comment: Well, .rar and .gz are quite different too, but WinRar works with both. It's just that the guys who created WinRar (or any other program) made it to work with this file formats. Same goes with .docx - the guys who wrote WinRar wrote it to be able to "understand" the .docx format. There is really no "law" about this. If you can make your software work with more formats, if it makes sense (it will be weird for an archiver to play mp3s), if it will be used by the users - do it.I don't know much about the .docx, but it doesn't need to have anything in common with .rar for WinRar to be able to use

Comment: WinRar was not built to work specifically with `docx`, as stated here: http://www.rarlab.com/otherfmt.htm - They have built some kind of generic reader that can deter if the file has meta data and to be able to generically read that data, this is what I am interested in, the generic route that needs to be taken to understand the file's structure as such.

Comment: Now I understand what you want to know, but cannot help you. I could probably give you some directions where to look for, but I think @Marc B's answer does that. Hope you find what you are looking for